# get_posts() seemingly ignoring post_type

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-posts

I am trying to grab posts of post type "leads" (see below for the code I am using) however the query produced (obtained via debug queries) is including the clause 'where post_type in ("leads", "leads", "product_description", "custom_products")'  [[notice leads is there twice]]

This leads me to think that somehow something is being hooked into this -- but shouldn't suppress_filters => true prevent this from happening? If that is the case what exactly is going on and how do I limit posts to just "leads" ?

```
  $args = array(
      'numberposts' => 5,
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'post_type' => 'leads',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
      'suppress_filters' => true
  );
  $result = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70887/wp-query-ignores-post-type-in-category-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a workaround for now, but would really love to know what is causing this. The workaround was obtained by removing changing "suppress_filters" to true and then adding a function that adds to the where clause of the SQL...

**But I would rather know how to fix this at the root rather than a bandaid**

My workaround was accomplished by adding the following to my functions.php:

```
function leads_post_type_where( $where ) {
$clause = "";
$post_types=get_post_types($args,'names');
foreach ($post_types as $post_type ) {
    if (trim($post_type)!="" && trim($post_type) != "ditl_post") {
        if ($clause==""){
            $clause .= "'$post_type'";
        } else {
            $clause .= ", '$post_type'";
        }
    }
}   

$where .= ' AND post_type NOT IN ('.$clause.')';
return $where;
}
```

Then updated my get_posts call to:

```
$args = array(
      'numberposts' => 5,
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'post_type' => 'leads',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
      'suppress_filters' => false
  );
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'leads_post_type_where' );
    $result = get_posts($args);
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'leads_post_type_where' );
```