# WP_Query ignores post_type in category view

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query, post-type

I have following query to select posts by my custom post-type. This works fine while being on the frontpage (the snippet is included in the sidebar). As soon it gets executed on a category page the `post_type` attribute is ignored and posts of the type "post" are returned. I guess this has to do with multiple loops but I have also tried to call `wp_reset_postdata();` and `wp_reset_query();` before and after.

```
$customPosts = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'mycustomtype', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));

while ( $customPosts->have_posts() ) : $customPosts->the_post(); 
    $thumbnailUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), "thumbnail");
    if ( !empty($thumbnailUrl)) {
      /* echo result */ 
    }   
endwhile;
```

Comment: There's no reason to use wp_reset_query when you're using a new WP_Query object.

Comment: Was just trying to get closer to a solution/workaround. Of course I was also trying without that statement. Removed them from the example to avoid confusion.

Comment: Obviously it works when using a direct DB query such as "$wpdb->get_results ...". Would prefer a standard WP-Tag solution though.

Comment: I copy/paste your code into the category.php file of a wordpress instance where I have a custom post enabled, it's working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, Simon. Meanwhile I've solved it with a different query. Will come back to you as soon I'm refactoring this part.

Comment: Hey, @david, how did you solve this with a _different query_? I'm encountering the same problem and haven't found any solution at all (besides from doing it with raw SQL).

Comment: This code should work fine. There are 2 reasons it could not work: 1. You have some typo in post type name. 2. There is some filter that is changing query (pre_get_posts, posts_where, etc.) Could you print_r $customPosts just before while and show me its content?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż 'posts_where' should not be the problem, because OP says that he had tried `'get_posts'`that function suppress filters as default, so 'posts_where' filters aren't taken into account. So my guess is there is a filter on `'pre_get_posts'` that not check for `$query->is_main_query()`.

Comment: What happens with `suppress_filters` turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using get_posts() instead?

```
 //#get access to post settings
    global $post;
    //#set parameters for extra loop
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mycustomtype', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    //#get posts 
    $customPosts = get_posts($args);
    //#loop through them
    foreach($customPosts as $post)
    {
        //#set all the loop functions to use data from this post
        setup_postdata($post);
        //#do what you want with the post
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why that would solve the issue.

Comment: This was indeed used in the first implementation but as toscho outlined it's not working as get_posts makes also use of WP_Query. So internally it should be the same. But thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Sorry, quite new to this and did not get notified of these comments. I just posted the get_posts approach as that is the one I tend to use and it has always worked out for me. There are a few approaches to multiple loops in WP and while in theory they tend to come down to WP_Query internally, the results can be odd and differ depending on what else you have going on in the template.

Comment: Here's an good explanation when to use which type of query: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: @toscho `get_posts` uses 'suppress_filters' = true by default, so if the problem was any filter on 'posts_where' using `get_posts` could solve the problem... but seems it's not the case.

Comment: this SHOULD indeed solve the problem, i would go one step further: `foreach($customPosts as $customPost)` to make sure $customPost was not overwritten by some other activity unintentionally. also, see my answer below.

Comment: @all who want to know why this would solve the issue. `WP_Query` requires you to set up your own loop adding complication to what can be handled more simply with `get_posts()`. `get_posts()` returns an array that can be iterated over completely outside the loop and other influences.

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve your issue, I was having the same problem, when I put this it worked perfectly.

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'mycustomtype', 
     'posts_per_page' => 12, 
     'orderby' => 'date', 
     'order' => 'DESC', 
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'tag' => 'mycustomtag',
     'cat' => 'mycustomcategory'
    );              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

Comment: You've copied code from the question and added two parameters that are not mentioned in the question, or in comments. How exactly is that supposed to solve the problem? This is the second questionable answer you've posted in a very short time. Please review [hoe to answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: It's not the array part that was the issue, that's done correctly. The bottom part of the code I shared, $the_query section is what helped make WordPress properly filter the custom post type by category. 

This answer resolved the other question I posted in as well. I tried a lot of different things and this is what got it working. That's how it helps.

Comment: The code posted is the functional equivalent of the code in the question but you've added parameters that are not part of the question. This does not solve *this* question but addresses a similar problem of your own.

Comment: Fine, I can delete this answer if you like.