# get_posts() not working in functions.php

Tags: get-posts, bbpress

If I use the following function in any theme template, it works as expected. However when trying to use it within an AJAX function in my functions.php, it returns empty.

```
$args = array (
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'post_type' => array('topic','reply'),
        'author' => 454
    );
$user_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Any ideas?

Here is the full function:

```
function he_delete_user(){

    $args = array (
        'numberposts' => 10,
        'post_type' => array('topic','reply'),
        'author' => 454
    );
    $user_posts = get_posts($args);

    if (empty($user_posts)){
        $response_array['status'] = 'false';    
        echo json_encode($response_array);
    }
    else{
        // delete all the user posts
        foreach ($user_posts as $user_post) {
            wp_delete_post($user_post->ID, true);
        }
        $response_array['status'] = 'success';    
        echo json_encode($response_array);
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_he_delete_user','he_delete_user');
```

Comment: can we see this in the context of your ajax function? are you sure the ajax function is executing and this code is actually running?

Comment: Added, but I have verified that it's running using the json response implemented in the function. The only issue is that get_posts returning nothing.

Comment: This is going to require debugging. Instead of `get_post`, create a `WP_Query` object. Then dump out (`var_dump`) the value of `$my_query->request` to see if there are any differences between the SQL.

Comment: If I do that, it shows that it's asking for posts! Not topics and replies. My syntax is verified correct, so I'm not sure why that's happening...

Comment: Seems to be the same issue: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62401/get-posts-seemingly-ignoring-post-type

Comment: include `global $post;` in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bandaid, not a fix. But it seems there is a bug within WP_Query, so I had to modify the query right before it was actually run in order for the post_type parameter to not be ignored.

1) I changed get_posts() to a WP_Query

2) I added this to my functions.php file:

```
function ban_parse_wp_query( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array('topic','reply') );
    return $query;
}
```

3) Then I modified the query with that action right before it was run and then remove the action right after so it would not affect any other queries:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'ban_parse_wp_query' );
$user_posts = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'ban_parse_wp_query' );
```